# How to deliver client code without serving it as a module, but outside the 'libs' folder?

Tags: socketstream

I am preparing a workaround for my problem described in my [socketStream/Node.js/Karma question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445963/how-to-test-an-angularjs-socketstream-node-js-app-using-karma).

I decided that karma is really not required to run Jasmine if you have a socketstream server to run your code anyway.

I include jasmine files through the SocketStream client code libs folder and that works (after editing the TestRunner.html file to make it a SocketStream view). The problem now is that my spec files to run the actual tests only run if I put them in the 'libs' folder.

I'd like to put them in a '/tests/specs' folder but when I do that they are delivered as modules.
Is there any way to mark a folder to behave the same as the 'libs' folder(s) i.e. not pack the content as a module?

Comment: Hi, is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way. However you can bundle up your tests in a content string and serve it with.

ss.client.assets.send('tests',--content--)